# Does Thompson's Calculus Made Easy have any discussion of implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, reference-request, education, implicit-differentiation

I didn't see it in the index but would like to read his treatment if there is one. The version I'm thinking of is here: http://calculusmadeeasy.org/

(Sorry if this isn't an appropriate question for this forum, but I thought it might be alright.)

ADDITIONAL EDIT: Page 2 of this article has a differential-based treatment of implicit differentiation, although I don't quite understand it, nor am I sure that it's identical to how Thompson treated it: http://math.oregonstate.edu/bridge/papers/differentials.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think B. Nunez gave a great answer, but I will follow on with a more specific example.  It's been a long time since I read Calculus Made Easy (CME), so apologies if this doesn't fit their methodology exactly.

In "traditional" calculus, you find the derivative with respect to a particular variable.  In CME, you find the derivative by incrementing each variable according to its own increment.  So, you replace $x$ with $x + dx$ and $y$ with $y + dy$.

So, let's say you have:

$$x^2 + y^2 = 1.$$

The CME approach would have you replace each $x$ with $x + dx$ and $y$ with $y + dy$.  This then becomes:

$$
(x + dx)^2 + (y + dy)^2 = 1 \\
x^2 + 2x\,dx + dx^2 + y^2 + 2y\,dy + dy^2 = 1 \\
2x\,dx + dx^2 + 2y\,dy + dy^2 = 0 \\
2x\,dx + 2y\,dy = 0 \\
2y\,dy = -2x\,dx \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x}{y}
$$

The simplification from step 2 to step 3 is because we subtracted the original equation from both sides.  The simplification from step 3 to step 4 is because the square of an infinitesimal is infinitely smaller than the original infinitesimal, and therefore infinitely more insignificant.  Then I just solved for $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

If you are interested, the way that I teach implicit differentiation is [here](https://journals.blythinstitute.org/ojs/index.php/cbi/article/view/29).

Comment: Wait is there any faster way to do it than actually expanding out the (x+dx) and (y+dy) ... but still using differentials?

Comment: Yes - you can write the derivative rules as differential rules.  Instead of the derivative of $y = x^n$ being $\frac{dy}{dx} = nx^{n - 1}$, you can write it purely in terms of the variables in the function, as $dy = nx^{n - 1}dx$.  Therefore, using these rules you would differentiate both sides by doing: $$d(x^2 + y^2) = d(1).$$  Addition rule gives you: $$d(x^2) + d(y^2) = d(1).$$  Applying basic rules gives you $$2x\,dx + 2y\,dy = 0.$$  That gets you to the 4th line above in basically 1 step.

Answer (score 3):

Thompson's approach to calculus is through the use of differentials, and thus his treatment of the derivative is essentially the same as what one would call "implicit differentiation" in standard textbooks: given an equation that relates $y(x)$ and $x$, differentiate all terms with respect to $x$ to obtain an implicit definition of $dy/dx$. Consequently, there's no need to distinguish between finding the derivative of a function and takes derivatives on an implicit expression. See e.g. http://calculusmadeeasy.org/6.html

Comment: Are any of the answers on that page actually examples of implicit differentiation, though? Or just Thompson's general approach? I still don't quite get how implicit differentiation ties in to his general approach (the latter of which I have *some* familiarity with).

Comment: See also my edit to the question.

Comment: Page 2 of the document you have provided seems exactly like Thompson's approach.

Comment: Yeah I still kinda need a worked example of Thompson-esque implicit differentiation though in order to reach full understanding. Maybe someone else will answer with that.